# vscode jest runner, illegible output colours in terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, jestjs

as you can see in the image below, showing yellow text on a white background, in an otherwise dark themed terminal. the jest runner output is completely illegible, none of my setting as far as I have looked should affect this.

I have searched for solutions but not found anything.

any help greatly appreciated.

[image: image showing illegible text output from jest runner test]

Answer (score 1):

[image: improved output format]

so i can use the terminal contrast ratio settings (as above) to get a more legible output.. not really the solution I'd like, but a workaround for now...